# Does Ruby's $! hold value only in rescue block?

Tags: ruby, rescue

```
begin
  raise 'foo'
rescue
  puts $!.inspect # => #<RuntimeError: foo>
ensure
  puts $!.inspect # => nil
end
puts $!.inspect # => nil
```

Googled around but didn't find a clear answer.

Just want to confirm the life-time(?) of `$!`, does it hold value only inside a `rescue` block?

Comment: I believe so, but I can't seem to confirm it.

Comment: Your `ensure` line and the line following it is making it more complex than needed.

Comment: remove the rescue block and check it with just an ensure ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$!` has the error in the rescue block, or in the the ensure block if there's no rescue block:

```
begin
  raise 'foo'
ensure
  puts $!.inspect # => #<RuntimeError: foo>
end
```

`$!` has the value `nil` everywhere else.

Comment: Thx! good to know. Probably will accept this as answer, just wait for one more day to be sure.

Comment: Your answer was definitely more concise than mine, while saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Original question was:

> Is Ruby's `$!` value only visible in rescue block?
>
> ```rb
>    begin
>      raise 'foo'
>    rescue
>      puts $!.inspect # => #<RuntimeError: foo>
>    end
>    puts $!.inspect # => nil
> ```
>
> Googled around but didn't find a clear answer.
>
> Just want to confirm the visibility of `$!`, is it only accessible inside a `rescue` block?

No, the read only variable `$!` is visible and available every where, and holds the value of `nil` except in rescue blocks.

It is also unique to each thread.  It is the current exception (the `English` library calls it `$ERROR_INFO`), and it is reset to `nil` once rescued, unless it is re-raised, then it is back to being the current exception.

From a file that has no other lines in it, we can see that indeed $! is visible.

```
puts defined?($!)
puts $!.inspect  

irb(main):001:0> defined?($!)
=> "global-variable"
irb(main):002:0> $!
=> nil
irb(main):003:0>
```

And in IRB we can see that it is defined and visible.

This really is not (or rather should not be) surprising at all, as the `$` designates that it is "global variable" and as such is globally visible.

I have not been able to find where it is not visible.  Even in BasicObject, it is visible.

```
irb(main):001:0> class BasicObject
irb(main):002:1>   def is_it_visible
irb(main):003:2>     defined?($!)                                                                                                 
irb(main):004:2>   end                                                                                                            
irb(main):005:1> end                                                                                                              
=> :is_it_visible
irb(main):006:0> BasicObject.allocate.is_it_visible
=> "global-variable"
irb(main):007:0>
```

I should add that it is one of the "read only"  variables as well.  Trying to assign to it would result in a NameError with a message explaining that it is a read-only variable.

Comment: sorry, my wording seems confused you. I should ask "does $! only hold value inside rescue block?".

Comment: No, your question was very clear.  Nothing confusing to me about it at all.  It holds the value of nil outside of those blocks, as you demonstrate in your code.

Comment: To clarify, since the question changed, this is in answer to the original question, which was clear.  This is, clearly, not the answer to the edited question.